# Compare pandas dataframe columns ignoring number in front of text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am creating 2 dataframes, concatenating them, and swapping the column levels and putting the column names next to each other. I am then comparing the columns. The data in my columns has a number with the format like 1-1 and then text. I would like to compare the text and ignore the number before it.

Example of what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Text": ['1-1 Text here1', '1-2 Text here2', '1-3 Text here3', '1-4 Text here4']})

    data2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Text": ['1-1 Text here1', '1-4 Text here', '1-5 Text here3', '1-6 Text here']})

    df_both = pd.concat([data1.set_index('ID'), data2.set_index('ID')], axis=1, keys=['Data1', 'Data2'])
    df_both = df_both.swaplevel(axis='columns')

    for column in df_both.columns.levels[0]:
        print(df_both.index[np.where(df_both[column]['Data1'] != df_both[column]['Data2'])])
```

Result: Int64Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name='ID')

Currently, the IDs 2, 3, and 4 are being returned because they are not equal. I would like to find a way to ignore the number before the text (ex. 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4) and only compare what follows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({
"ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"Text": ['1-1 Text here1', '1-2 Text here2', '1-3 Text here3', '1-4 Text here4']})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({
"ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"Text": ['1-1 Text here1', '1-4 Text here', '1-5 Text here3', '1-6 Text here']})

df_both = pd.concat([data1.set_index('ID'), data2.set_index('ID')], axis=1, keys=['Data1', 'Data2'])
df_both = df_both.swaplevel(axis='columns')

s1 = df_both.loc[:,('Text','Data1')].str.extract('(\d-\d)(.+)')[1]
s2 = df_both.loc[:,('Text','Data2')].str.extract('(\d-\d)(.+)')[1]

m = s1.eq(s2)

print(df_both[m])
```

```
              Text                
             Data1           Data2
ID                                
1   1-1 Text here1  1-1 Text here1
3   1-3 Text here3  1-5 Text here3
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the number before the text, you can split the 'Text' column on the first space character, and keep only the second part. This can be done using the str.split() method of pandas Series, and then accessing the second element of the resulting list using the str accessor. You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Text": ['1-1 Text here1', '1-2 Text here2', '1-3 Text here3', '1-4 Text here4']
    })

    data2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "Text": ['1-1 Text here1', '1-4 Text here', '1-5 Text here3', '1-6 Text here']
    })

    # Split 'Text' column on the first space character and keep only the second part
    data1['Text'] = data1['Text'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[1]
    data2['Text'] = data2['Text'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[1]

    df_both = pd.concat([data1.set_index('ID'), data2.set_index('ID')], axis=1, keys=['Data1', 'Data2'])
    df_both = df_both.swaplevel(axis='columns')

    for column in df_both.columns.levels[0]:
        # Split 'Text' column on the first space character and keep only the second part
        data1_col = data1['Text'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[1]
        data2_col = data2['Text'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[1]

        print(df_both.index[np.where(data1_col != data2_col)])
```